# Short circuiting operation in Kotlin sequences

Tags: kotlin, functional-programming, sequence, declarative

I've been wondering if there is any chance of implementing sequence which executes some operation **`n`** times using `map` operator, but can terminate that execution during processing on the 'go'? Here is an imperative code which I'm trying to implement using Kotlin sequences:

```
val offers = mutableListOf<String>()
for (pageNumber in FIRST_PAGE_NUMBER until numberOfPages) {
     val offersInPage = findByPage(query, pageSize, pageNumber)
     offers.addAll(offersInPage)

     if(offersInPage.size == 5)
         break
}
```

The main thing is that I would like to hang up processing any further requests to external service when response from the previous one meets some conditions.

When trying to implement it in more declarative way I ended up with something like this:

```
IntArray(numberOfPages)
    .asSequence()
    .map { findByPage(query, pageSize, it) }
    .takeWhile { it.size == 5 }
    .flatten()
    .toList()
```

But the `findByQuery` method is invoked **`n`** times and then the result is filtered. Is there any operator which help me implement something like terminating that lazy operation once given condition is met?

Answer (score 2):

The sequence works exactly as you expected. It performs on map checks the takeWhile condition and does only continue if it is true.

One problem could be `IntArray(numberOfPages)`. This creates an array of `0` of the size `numberOfPages`. So you iterate over a sequence of `0` and not the page numbers. You can simply change this to the for loop condition.

```
(FIRST_PAGE_NUMBER until numberOfPages)
    .asSequence()
```

Another problem could be the `takeWhile`. In the for loop you stop *after* the first element with a `size == 5`. But in the sequence you stop *before* the first element with a `size != 5`. The simplest solution for this problem is to find another condition that would break the loop before `offers.addAll(offersInPage)` will be executed. If this is not possible you can use something like this:

```
fun <T> Sequence<T>.takeWhileEndInclusive(predicate: (T) -> Boolean) = object : Sequence<T> {
    val sequence = this@takeWhileEndInclusive

    override fun iterator() = object : Iterator<T> {
        val iterator = sequence.iterator()
        var nextState: Int = -1
        var nextItem: T? = null
        var found = false

        private fun calcNext() {
            if (!found && iterator.hasNext()) {
                val item = iterator.next()
                if (!predicate(item)) {
                    found = true
                }
                nextState = 1
                nextItem = item
                return
            }
            nextState = 0
        }

        override fun next(): T {
            if (nextState == -1)
                calcNext()
            if (nextState == 0)
                throw NoSuchElementException()
            @Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
            val result = nextItem as T

            nextItem = null
            nextState = -1
            return result
        }

        override fun hasNext(): Boolean {
            if (nextState == -1)
                calcNext()
            return nextState == 1
        }
    }
}
```

This is a slightly adjusted version of the default `takeWhile` implementation.

Usage:

```
(FIRST_PAGE_NUMBER until numberOfPages)
    .asSequence()
    .map { findByPage(query, pageSize, it) }
    .takeWhileEndInclusive { it.size != 5 }
    .flatten()
    .toList()
```